# Access: 2 roles on the same DB with different roles

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access Database on the SharePoint and two user's roles that have to work on it:

- **Role1** is given to a single user. He can manage all the forms of the DB with the possibility to change all the tables. These forms will require many future releases.
- **Role2** is given to many users. They can manage only one form that is effective only on a single table of the DB. He doesn't (and mustn't) need to see/manage the others forms/tables (they are a lot). The form used for this role will not require future releases.

What it the best practice to manage this? I thought about the following 2 solutions but probably there is a third one that is better.

**Solution #1**

Having 2 different Access files linked to the same DB: one with all the forms (that I give to Role1) and one with only one form (that I give to Role2).

**Solution #2**

Having a single Access file that I give to both the users. Role1 has read/write access to all forms. Role2 can see only a specific form and has no read/write access to other forms.

Comment: I would choose option 2.

Comment: @June7 thanks. I have detailed more the issue (Role1 has high-frequency change forms, while Role2 has a single form that will never change). Will this change your answer?

Comment: IMHO, If you have read write access to an Access Database  (AKA not (accde, accdr)) then any security you provide is useless. Because the user can easily bypass or remove the restriction.

Comment: Agree that security with Access is minimal. I would choose to manage 1 frontend and use code to determine which form is presented to user. But use two files if you prefer. There is no 'right' answer, only suggestion and opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend **solution #2** otherwise if you change the logic in the front end you have to change it always twice and this is really annoying. Also, if you forget to change both versions and you had a huge change in the logic, you have people working with the old version and people working with the new version.

What I normally do is the following. I have a table `tblDeveloperAccess` with the `ID` of your **Role1**. At the start of the first form load event I have the following code:

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tbDeveloperAccess", dbOpenSnapshot)

rs.FindFirst "ID = '" & Environ("USERNAME") & "'"

If rs.NoMatch Then

    DoCmd.NavigateTo "acNavigationCategoryObjectType", "acNavigationGroupTables"
    DoCmd.SelectObject acForm, vbNullString, True
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdWindowHide

    DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo

End If
```

Basically I am hiding the ribbon and the object navigation. You can go even further and disable the context menu and the "Shift + DblClick"-Trick (on your database file). And of course I disable the possibilty on the start form to get into the design view.

Comment: Any approach relying on the user being unable to view or alter code of an uncompiled, unencrypted database is fundamentally flawed and offers very little security. You can toggle the Shift + Double click option by directly editing the database through DAO and another VBA program, disable VBA altogether, etc.

Comment: Yes thats true. For more security more effort would be needed.